# dynamically get rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, active-relation

If I have an association name as a string, is there a way I can get a handle on the association object?

For example:

```
o = Order.first
```

o.customer will give me the customer object that this order belongs to.

If I have:

```
o = Order.first
relationship = 'customer'
```

i would like to do something like:

```
customer = eval("o.#{relationship}")
```

I know eval is a terrible option and I should avoid it. What is the best way to do this (as eval does not work in this example).

I did have this working:

```
customer = o.association(relationship)
```

I later found out that the association is not part of the public API and should not be used. Because when I took a line of code I had higher up the page off (that referenced that relationship) it stopped working.

Any ideas would be awesome!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about just doing this?

```
customer = o.send(relationship)
```

Comment: The call to #to_sym isn't needed; send can handle strings.

Comment: Wow, like magic! Is send a rails or ruby method? I couldn't find documentation on it. Incidentally, i've never used it so i have no idea how this is working. Thanks again!

Comment: Send is a ruby method. It can also take arguments. You can find the documentation on #send here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: Your answer was so quick it wont even let me accept it yet, I will in a few min, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For those who fears using `send`:

```
o.association(relationship).scope
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `try()` which will allow you manage any `undefined method` errors if the relationship doesn't exist.

```
relationship = 'customer'
foo = 'foo'

customer = o.try(relationship)
# > [
#     [0] #<Customer...

customer = o.try(foo)
# > nil
```

vs `send()`:

```
customer = o.send(relationship)
# > [
#     [0] #<Customer... 

customer = o.send(foo)
# > NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<Order...
```